# How to hide overflow characters of a div when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few div elements, I want to hide overflow characters when div resizing like this

[image] to this [image]
how to do this every time i resize page.

Can i do it from CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following css to the div which contains the text:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will simply add the three dots at the end of the line whenever the text is longer than the div.

Note: This works only for a 1 line text.